# Accessing Jcomments permission tab in joomla / Enabling hidden menus

Tags: joomla, comments, rating

The copy of joomla i'm using is edited by the super administrator to **not** to show the unnecessary menus like installing/uninstalling modules etc etc..
but now, i want to set the permissions of Jcomments and i can't find the menu anywhere to do that..
i found a simple settings page using **administrator/index.php?option=com_jcomments&task=settings**

but i can't get to the permissions page since it uses ajax(i guess)..
i thought of editing the setting in the Database directly but that'd be a very *bad* practice..
so,

1) Can anyone tell me how to enable those menus **or** at least how to reach them.

2) If not possible i wanna uninstall the old version of Jcomments and install it with a new one

please pour in your advices and suggetions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the menu in

> /administrator/modules/mod_menu/helper.php

and the menu permissions in

> /libraries/joomla/user/authorization.php

However, if you even can't (un)install something, I think you are only a Manager (not Administrator). (Can you create new Users?) So maybe it's just Joomla that is adapting the menu to your role's permission. More infos to user roles at [Joomla! Docs](http://docs.joomla.org/Changing_user_groups).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the administration *template* has been changed. The default template is "khepri" located at `/administrator/templates/khepri`. See if you can find a way to revert to that.

All templates will be folders under `/administrator/templates`, apart from a `system` folder which is always there. If khepri is the only template on the system, you'll have to dig into the HTML (look at `index.php` in that folder) and see if options have been removed or commented out.

If you still can't get the menus back, just download a fresh copy of Joomla and copy the khepri folder from that to your current version.